# codeblocks output differs from online compilers

Tags: c, linked-list, ide, codeblocks

In short, I should have "  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 ".
When executed in CodeBlocks instead of 0 i am getting random numbers. But When compiling using  online compilators I am getting expected output. Which output is reliable? Online or CodeblockIDE's?
If needed there is the code that is linked-list practise: creating, inputting data elements, deleting at specified point and finally outputing the result.

```
#include <stdio.h>       
#include <stdlib.h>      
#include <malloc.h>     

typedef int DataType;    

typedef struct Node
{
    DataType data;
    struct Node *next;
} SLNode;

void ListInitiate(SLNode **head)        /* Initialization */
{
/* If there is memory space, apply the head node space and make the head pointer point to the head node */

    if((*head = (SLNode *)malloc(sizeof(SLNode))) == NULL) exit(1);
    (*head)->next = NULL;          /* set the last of the list as Null */
}


int ListLength(SLNode *head)     /* Get the size of the linked list */
{
    SLNode *p = head;             
    int size = 1;

    while(p->next != NULL)         /*count with loop*/
    {
        p = p->next;
        size ++;
    }
    return size;
}

int ListInsert(SLNode *head, int i, DataType x)

/* Insert a node that contains the data element x before the node ai (0 ≤ i ≤ size) of the linked list with header */

{
    SLNode *p, *q;
    int j;

    p = head;             /* p points to the head*/
    j = -1;               /* the initial value of j is -1*/
    while(p->next != NULL && j < i - 1)
    /* Finally let pointer p point to data element ai-1 node */
    {
        p = p->next;
        j++;
    }

    if(j != i - 1)
    {
        printf("Insert position parameter wrong!");
        return 0;
    }

    /* q points to the new node*/
    if((q = (SLNode *)malloc(sizeof(SLNode))) == NULL) exit(1);
    q->data = x;

    /* There is an error blow*/
    q->next = p->next;
    p->next = q;
    return 1;
}

int ListDelete(SLNode *head, int i, DataType *x)
/* delete the node ai of the list with a header*/
/* put the data element of the node in x. If success, return 1; if fail, return 0*/

{
    SLNode *p, *s;
    int j;
    p = head;
    j = -1;

    while(p->next != NULL && p->next->next!= NULL && j < i - 1)

    /*Finally let pointer p point to data element ai-1 node */

    {
        p = p->next;
        j++;
    }

    if(j!= i - 1)
    {
        printf("Insert position parameter wrong!");
        return 0;
    }


    s = p->next;         /*s points to ai*/
    *x = s->data; /*Assign the data field value of the node pointed by pointer s to x */
    p->next = s->next;     /* delete ai*/
    free(s);          /* free the memory space of s */
    return 1;
}

int ListGet(SLNode *head, int i, DataType *x)
/*The function of taking the data element ai is similar to deleting ai function, but do not delete the data element ai node*/
{
    SLNode *p;
    int j;

    p = head;
    j = 0;
    while(p->next != NULL && j < i)
    {
        p = p->next;
        j++;
    }

    if(j != i)
    {
        printf("The position of the parameter is wrong!");
        return 0;
    }


    *x = p->data;

    return 1;
}

void Destroy(SLNode **head)
{
    SLNode *p, *p1;

    p = *head;
    while(p != NULL)
    {
        p1 = p;
        p = p->next;
        free(p1);
    }
    *head = NULL;
}

void main(void)
{
    SLNode *head;
    int i , x;
    ListInitiate(&head);
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if(ListInsert(head, i, i+1) == 0)      /*insert ten data elements*/
        {
            printf("Error!! \n");
            return;
        }
    }

    if(ListDelete(head, 4, &x) == 0)     /* delete data element 5*/
    {
        printf("error! \n");
        return;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < ListLength(head); i++)
    {
        if(ListGet(head, i, &x) == 0)      /* take out the element*/
        {
            printf("Error! \n");
            return;
        }
        else printf("%d    ", x);        /* show data elements*/
    }

    Destroy(&head);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with the logic of your code. The good output is the Code::Blocks one.

The problem is within the `insertNode` function. Its behaviour is the following : it finds the i-1th node and create a new node after it. If `i = 0`, the 0th element is found in the first iteration of your first loop and there will be no error after that, because `j = i - 1 = -1`. Never in your code you edit the data of the head.
Furthermore, each time you call your `insertNode` function, you ask for the value of the new node to be its position + 1.

So you will have this :

```
----------       -----       -----
| random |  ---> | 1 |  ---> | 2 |  ---> etc.
----------       -----       -----
  head            0th         1st
```

After that, in the `listGet` function, you make a misconception about the way your list is made. As an exemple, when will call `listGet(head, 0, &x)`, the condition `p->next != NULL && j < i` will always be satisfied at the first iteration, meaning that the returned node is not the 0th, but the head. You should instead write :

```
j = -1;  // 0 become -1
while(p->next != NULL && j < i)
{
    p = p->next;
    j++;
}
```

Moreover, you must change the bound of your loop in the main. Indeed, the `listLength` returns the number of elements in your list (here, 10), but the indexation does not begin from 1 bt from 0, meaning that you must not stop at 10 (because there is no 10th node) but at 9. Therefore you must write :

```
for(i = 0; i < ListLength(head) - 1; i++)
{
    if(ListGet(head, i, &x) == 0)      /* take out the element*/
    {
        printf("Error! \n");
        return 1;
    }
    else printf("%d    ", x);        /* show data elements*/
}
```

There is another point that is not related to this problem but that you must correct anyway : your destroy function.

```
void Destroy(SLNode **head)
{
    SLNode *p, *p1;

    p = *head;
    while(p != NULL)
    {
        p1 = p;
        p = p->next;
        
        /* make NULL assignment here */
        p1->next = NULL;
        
        free(p1);
    }
    /* head has been already freed in the above loop
    *  do not try to manipulate it */
    // *head = NULL;
}
```